# How can I get LogIntegral[z] to be printed as "li[z]"?

Tags: output-formatting, special-functions

I have no problem with the current formatting of the function, but for the sake of the reader less familiar with *Mathematica* functions, is there a way to define, say, `li = LogIntegral` so that any form of `LogIntegral` in my output is presented as `li` instead? [This seems to be the way it's usually presented](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html).

Comment: `LogIntegral[z] // TraditionalForm`?  -- Sometimes `TraditionalForm` is the default output form.  In output cells, it's `StandardForm`.  E.g., `Plot[LogIntegral[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> LogIntegral[z]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 that definitely works, but let's say I want to express `LogIntegral` as `li` while still in `StandardForm`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll make this brief: it's a job for a `MakeBoxes` rule. In this case a particularly simple one:

```
MakeBoxes[li : LogIntegral, StandardForm] := InterpretationBox["li", li]
```

Now `LogIntegral` prints as `li`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, `Format[]` seems to be done for that :

```
Unprotect[LogIntegral]
Format[LogIntegral[z_]] := li[z]
Protect[LogIntegral]
```